# How to create a border image?

Tags: html, css, alignment, padding

I am trying to create an image border with the following:

background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px;

The image shows the border but takes up all the space to the right.  So instead of the border enclosing the image, the border extends to the white space on the right... what can i do to fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the border to the image itself, rather than a container around the image.

Comment: for e.g like this:  <img src="source" border: "1px solid #CCCCCC"></img>   thanks

Comment: @AAA the `img` tag cannot have children, and should be properly closed: `<img ... />`

Comment: `<img src="source" style="border: 1px solid #CCC">`